# How can I Make SOAP Requests and Responses in Android?

Tags: android, web-services, soap

I want to connect my remote SOAP web services for that I have WSDL file how can I make soapRequest through XML and get the response and hold in XML output through Android By using Ksoap2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [sample](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-ksoap2-android-and-parsing-output-data)

Comment: I have to downvote this because the question doesn't show research or effort. There are numerous soap implementations you can choose, pick one and search for examples/documentation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015956/getting-name-space-method-name-from-soap-wsdl/12016034#12016034